# Rails 3 - Validates :handle does not equal one of these words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my app, I allow users to create a handle.

```
user.rb (:handle)
```

What I would like to do is have a blacklist of words that can not be used, like "support", "staff", bad words etc...

Is that possible using a validates method in the rails model?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is validates_exclusion_of

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000089

Disadvantage: it is sensitive to case, so "bad" and "Bad" are different words.

Comment: That, what about adding a rule for making sure it the username doesn't include 'Support' meaning 'Support123' would error ?

Comment: I think validates_exclusion_of is pretty much useless, because it should work with regular expressions and not (case sensitive) strings. So you 'll have to write your own validation. See 5.3) and 6) in the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless